# why won't Jenkins write the ouput of my jmeter test to the specified logfile?

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, jmeter

I have set up Jenkins to run my parameterized jmeter test (with the kind assistance of knowledgeable users here). I'm not using any other build technologies at the moment. I can run my tests and see the results in Jenkins as expected. 
 However Jenkins is not writing the test data to my specified logfile. Here is my Windows batch script in Jenkins: 
 `C:\Users\MikeL\Documents\apache-jmeter\bin\jmeter.bat -n -t C:\Users\MikeL\Documents\apache-jmeter\bin\testApp.jmx -l log.jtl -Jenv=%env% -JloopCount=%loopCount%` 
 if I run `jmeter -n -t testApp.jmx -l log.jtl -Jenv=dev -JloopCount=1` from the windows cmd prompt inside of jmeters bin dir It does create the log file as expected. 
 If anyone knows why the Jenkins script won't output it I'd be very obliged.

Comment: My initial thought is to ask what user Jenkins is running under on your machine.  Without knowing more this smells of permissions issues, your jenkins instance might not have permissions to write the log file in your users documents.  It would be handy to know what's happening in jmeter.bat (particularly where Jenkins is trying to write the log file).  That said if you go into this job's folder under jenkins and then go to the Build folder Jenkins saves the console output log there, if that is sufficient you might use your script to copy that file.

Comment: @Tuffwer Thanks for the help. I can see the log file in the Jenkins build folder. that should work. I think you may be right about the permissions issue. I haven't explicitly set up any security since installing and the installation was in a program files dir that wasn't in my user dir.

Comment: I just had another thought, I assume log.jtl is the file you are specifying. You might create a log directory somewhere you know for sure Jenkins can write to (such as in the Jenkins home directory) and provide a full path to a logfile in that directory in your batch script. Obviously you can setup this folder anywhere Jenkins can write too.